# Logarithms of matrices that are close in trace distance are close?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, limits, logarithms, nuclear-norm

Let us define the 1-norm or nuclear norm by the following expressions where $\dagger$ represents the conjugate transpose of a matrix.

$$||A||_{1} = \text{Tr}(\sqrt{A^\dagger A})$$

The one norm represents the sum of the absolute eigenvalues of $A$.

Now, choose $\delta > 0$. We find two positive definite matrices $\rho$ and $\sigma$ that satisfy

$$||\rho - \sigma||_1 \leq \delta$$

Can one say anything about $||\log(\rho) - \log(\sigma)||_1$? Intuitively, it seems that for any $\epsilon > 0$, I should be able to find a $\delta$ such that if $||\rho - \sigma||_1 \leq \delta$, then $||\log(\rho) - \log(\sigma)||_1 \leq \epsilon$. However, I'm not sure if this is true or how to proceed with a proof.

Comment: Are you looking for a $\delta$ independent of either $\rho$ or $\sigma$?  If so, then you're trying to show that the matrix log is uniformly continuous, which is not true.

Comment: If you restrict your domain (for instance, by putting a lower bound on the absolute value of the eigenvalues of $A$), then I believe you can get such a global inequality

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, thank you - Your comments have answered my question. I can accept them if you move it into an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible to find such a $\delta$ that is independent of $\rho$ or $\sigma$ since the matrix logarithm fails to be uniformly continuous over its domain.

For instance: if we take
$$
\rho = e^{-t} I, \quad \sigma = e^{-2t} I
$$
for some $t > 0$, then we compute $\|\rho - \sigma\|_1 = \frac{1 - e^{-t}}{e^t}n$.  On the other hand, we compute $\|\log(\rho) - \log(\sigma)\|_1 = nt$.  It follows that $\frac{\|\log(\rho) - \log(\sigma)\|_1}{\|\rho - \sigma\|_1}$ can be made arbitrarily large.

On the other hand, I believe that if we restrict the domain of the logarithm (for instance, by imposing a positive lower bound on the real part of the eigenvalues of $A$), then we can ensure uniform continuity over this restricted domain.